# Fluid compare dates

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to compare two dates. I want to make a condition which checks if the date in my database is older than the date in two days.

Here are my two variables:

```
{<f:format.date format="d.m.Y">+2 days</f:format.date>}
{<f:format.date format="d.m.Y">{day.valid}</f:format.date>}
```

I want to solve this in the template, not in the model or the controller.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assign your date to variable »yourdate«.

```
<f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: '+2 days', format: 'Y-m-d')} < {f:format.date(date: yourdate, format: 'Y-m-d')}">
    <f:then>
       yourdate is smaller than now + 2 days.
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        yourdate is greater than or equal to now + 2 days.
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Comment: the closing '</f:if>' can't be seen nor copied, even it's there.

Comment: it needed some whitespace

Answer (score 2):

Here is my current solution which adds in a current date and does some calculations with the date from the content.

In the controller, add the current date to the data:

`$this->view->assign('date_now', new \DateTime());`

This is available as {date_now} in fluid then:

```
<f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: date_now, format: '(Y-m-d)')} > {f:format.date(date: '{event.date}-4 weeks', format: '(Y-m-d)')}">
   <f:then>
      <p>Event date is past</p>
   </f:then>
   <f:else>
      <p>Event date is upcoming</p>
   </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Note how on the right side, where some calculation is done, additional quotes and curly brackets come in (`'{event.date}-4 weeks'`).

PS I prefer the `Y-m-d` format to `U` for a date comparison, as we don't want to compare the current time – just the date.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date to an unix timestamp using `format="U"` and compare them. You need to add a variable which contains the comparing date.

```xml
<f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: day.valid, format: 'U')} > {f:format.date(date: date_compare, format: 'U')}">
    Date is valid
</f:if>
```

Comment: Depending on what is passed in, this may give you more than dates, as the timestamps will contain minutes as well.

Comment: ... so if you need to know if you're just on the next DAY, Y-m-d is more adequate

Answer (score 0):

Actually: because DateTime has a `getTimestamp` method (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php, since 5.3.0) which perfectly conforms to the supported getter method naming in Fluid, the following is perfectly possible. Given $date1 and $date2 are both DateTime instances assigned to the template:

```
<f:if condition="{date1.timestamp} < {date2.timestamp}">...</f:if>
```

Will compare the two dates as *unix timestamp integers* without the need to format the dates. So for your case, assign a `$date = (new \DateTime('now'))->modify('+2 days');` from your controller action and compare to that in Fluid. Or just assign the `time()` timestamp and compare directly to that, skipping the DateTime usage.